# Place order button disabled when cart total is 0

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.1.5

I have enabled zero subtotal checkout in **Magento ver. 2.1.5** and now I have a problem with the "Place Order" button being disabled if the value of the cart is $0

If the order value is **over** **$0** in the cart then the button is enabled, I have tested with the default Luma theme and my own custom theme both with the same issue.

It also shows no payment methods on the OPC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

***It may be your Magento checkout setting issue. Please check your cart total is greater or equal to Minimum Amount.***

Go to Configuration in Backend :

```
  Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales > Minimum Order Amount

  Set "Minimum order Amount" : enabled and "Minimum amount" to :0
```

Comment: I have this set already and the button is still disabled